# What conditions cause a party to naturally occur?

Tags: terraria

According to the change log for Terraria 1.3.2 (emphasis is mine):

> Parties have now been added! You can start your own via the Party Girl's Party Center or the Town NPCs may start one, **if certain conditions are met**

What conditions must be met for a party to naturally occur? The wiki entry on the [Party event](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Party) doesn't list anything specific.

Comment: While I don't know if this is all, the wiki mentions a cooldown of 5-11 days. Also I imagine that you need to have the party girl moved in for any parties to start. This is mostly conjecture on my part.

Comment: @Nick is right, for parties to occur, the party girl must move in. A possible condition may be bosses slain, but don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this link](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Party), a party has a random chance of naturally occurring at dawn, and no conditions need to be met for a party to be naturally hosted- but I'd guess you'd need at least one NPC in your world to act as the host for a party.

Edit: 
 I've tested the theory and have conformed that a party can naturally occur in a world without the need for a party machine. The world I used was a small, non-Expert mode pre-hardmode world. The only NCPs that had moved in were the guide, merchant, dye trader, arms dealer, demolitionist, nurse, painter, clothier, mechanic and dryad.

Comment: Where in the link does it state that there are no conditions required?

Comment: In the third sentence of the first paragraph it says, "A party has a random chance of occurring at any particular dawn, without the need for having a placed Party Center near the involved NPCs."                                   I'm sorry I responded so late, and if I inconvenienced you in any way, I might as well apologize for that too. Thank you for you patience.

Comment: That doesn't prove there aren't any other conditions that, say, people haven't discovered yet (the update is quite new still).

Comment: I've tested the theory and have conformed that a party can naturally occur in a world without the need for a party machine. The world I used was a small, non-Expert mode pre-hardmode world.The only NCPs that had moved in were the guide, merchant, dye trader, arms dealer, demolitionist, nurse, painter, clothier, mechanic and dryad.